# Child of flexed child takes all the space

Tags: css, flexbox

I have 2 divs that are children of a flexed element. Inside one of them, I want to have another div, that takes only the space it needs for its content. Instead it takes all the space.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my demo:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.c-1 {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 3;
  
  background-color: green;
}

.c-2 {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  
  background-color: red;
}

.c-1-inner {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="c-1">
    <div class="c-1-inner">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have set height:100% ... so it will take all the space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the behaviour you're after? `width: fit-content;`

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.c-1 {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 3;
  
  background-color: green;
}

.c-2 {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  
  background-color: red;
}

.c-1-inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: fit-content;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="c-1">
    <div class="c-1-inner">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 100% height on `.c-1-inner`...it is  not required.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.c-1 {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 3;
  background-color: green;
}

.c-2 {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.c-1-inner {
  /* height: 100%; */
  background-color: blue;
}

.box {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="c-1">
    <div class="c-1-inner">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-2"></div>
</div>
```